# Advanced differential equations solutions manual

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently doing some graduate work in advanced mathematics and came upon this book

[The Theory of Differential Equations
Classical and Qualitative  Kelley, Walter G., Peterson, Allan C.](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441957825#otherversion=9781441957832)

It has some excellent exercises and I wanted to know there exists any solution manual for this book. I've been scouring the web and haven't come up with anything nor any universities that used it for hw exercirses etc.

Can anyone recommend any book with similar topics with worked solutions, specifically chapter 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always email one of the authors considering this is a new text - often they are happy to provide a manual so long as you are not to distribute it online. But do bear in mind however, that many texts don't have any solutions whatsoever.

If not, a great text on ordinary and partial differential equations which covers the theory and applications is [*Elementary Differential Equations - Boyce & Diprima.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elementary-Differential-Equations-William-Boyce/dp/047003940X)  It is to the level of undergraduate if this is what you wanted

Another, but more advanced book is a more qualitative outlook on ODE's: [*Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems and Linear Algebra - Smale](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Equations-Dynamical-Systems-Mathematics/dp/0123495504)

*A pdf *may or may not* exist online which I would not condone to use of course.